# Testnet transaction is not broadcasted/confirmed within 5 hours

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoin-testnet

Trying to send transaction using python lib https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib

We debugged rest API which publishes transaction to to service chain.so and it was successful, also we can see this TX here:

https://chain.so/tx/BTCTEST/98d9f2bc3f65b0ca81f775f43c2f48b6ffe29fcfa06779c7ab299709ea7fc639

DST address is our BitPay testnet wallet,
SRC addresses come generated from python-bitcoinlib using wallet.get_key()

Also we even can't find it on other services.

Also we tried same to to post transaction to bitaps.com and we can't see it there too.

Probably someone can give a clue where to look, what can be wrong and why Confidence on chain.so is 0%. Probably you can recommend other service?

Code is very straightforward:

```
wallet = wallet_create_or_open(name='MainWallet', network='testnet', witness_type='segwit')
transaction = wallet.send_to(
  to_address=body.address,
  amount=decimal_to_satoshi(body.amount),
  fee='low', offline=True,
)
transaction.send(offline=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an issue:

```
Raw hex into https://tbtc.bitaps.com/broadcast but there is an error it shows "Broadcast transaction failed: min relay fee not met, 111 < 141 (code 66)"

Based on the error it seems that I am sending tBTC with a below minimum fee.
```